# Vertical/Horizontal scroll with fixed column and header

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm working on this sort of gradebook. So on the left column are the students, and on the right  column are the grades. I need to make scrollable the areas marked red and green. So scrolling vertical will move grades and students up and down and headers should stay in place, and scrolling horizontal, will move the grades and grades headers left and right, but student column should stay in place.

Does anybody know how to archieve this? Please advise!
I managed to do it separately but can't make it work both together.

[image]

Comment: post the code you have so we can help you.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll`

Comment: is this an HTML table ? , would you dare to reset display and use position:sticky ? , if yes, you can take a look at https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abboqbR html table with sticky horizontal and vertical th  and cells scrolling on both axis. demo can even be resized  ... you should really improve your question with code and attemps you've made because if te codepen is very similar to your needs, it might be very far from what you have

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you so much! position: sticky; did the magic. I really didn't post code on this question because I was looking for a change of approach completely. Thanks a lot a again for posting